Why does the Text in compose always need extra height to display text？
I Develop a App in Android with Kotlin compose
I need the text to fit closely with the text and edge.
@Composable
fun pixelToSp(px: Int): TextUnit {
    return (px / (LocalDensity.current.density * LocalConfiguration.current.fontScale)).sp
}

Text(text = "Á哈gÁ哈gÁ哈gÁ哈gÁ哈gÁ哈gÁ哈gÁ哈gÁ哈gÁ哈gÁ哈gÁ哈gÁ哈g",
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .border(1.dp, Color.Red)
        ,
        style = TextStyle(
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontSize = pixelToSp(250),
        ),
        color = Color.Green
    )


I measured the Height of the text roughly.

Found that the 250 box does not fully contain text.

so,I set lineHeight to fontsize，be overlap in red box.

The blue box in image, a somewhat inexplicable height between the edges of Text and text , unless you adjust the baseline about +0.3f. it doesn't look official.
I don't want extra height and overlap,please.

Note: LocalConfiguration.current.fontScale 1.0
